# didn't get default path when i logout from dashboard

Tags: angular

I don't know how to set default path when i logout .

const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',  // default path
component: HomeContentComponent,
},
{
path: '',
component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
data: { roles: [Privilege.PQ_CREATE, Privilege.PQ_APPROVE] },
children: [
{path: 'pqDashboard', component: PqDashboardComponent, data: {extraParameter: 'dashboardsMenu'}},
{path: 'pqStepper', component: PqStepperComponent, data: {extraParameter: ''}},
{path: 'pqRecreate', component: PqRecreateComponent, data: {extraParameter: ''}}
]
},
{
path: '',
component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
data: { roles: [Privilege.PQ_SUPPLIER] },
children: [
{path: 'supplierDashboard', component: SupplierDashboardComponent, data: {extraParameter: ''}},
//  {path: 'purchasePQ', component: PurchasePqComponent, data: {extraParameter: ''}},
]
},
{
path: '',
component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
data: { roles: [Privilege.PQ_ADMIN] },
children: [
{path: 'adminDashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent, data: {extraParameter: ''}},
]
},
{
path: '',
component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
data: { roles: [Privilege.SUPER_ADMIN] },
children: [
{path: 'superAdminDashboard', component: SuperAdminDashboardComponent, data: {extraParameter: ''}},
]
},
{
path: '',
component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
data: { roles: [Privilege.PQ_EVALUATOR] },
children: [
{path: 'evaluatorDashboard', component: EvaluatorDashboardComponent, data: {extraParameter: ''}},
{path: 'evaluatorComparisionSheet' , component: ComparisionSheetComponent, data : {extraParameter : ''}},
]
},
{
path: '',
component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
data: { roles: [Privilege.PQ_OPENER] },
children: [
{path: 'opnerDashboard', component: OpenerDashboardComponent, data: {extraParameter: ''}},
{path: 'openerComparisionSheet' , component: OpenerComparisionSheetComponent, data : {extraParameter : ''}},
]
},

];

This is my routing file . any one can help me out.

Comment: Can you follow some [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve readability of code?

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to default path inject in constructour Router

```
constructor(
    private router: Router
) {}
```

then you can call in logout function

`this.router.navigateByUrl('');` or `this.router.navigate([]);`

see documentation https://angular.io/api/router/Router